# Unable to connect to Database on Azure using Query Editor. However able to fetch data from PowerAPP and PowerBI

Tags: python, authentication, azure-sql-database, azureportal

We've setup an Azure SQL Database and unable to login using a Query Editor on the Azure Portal. However, live connections to the SQL seem to be fine , Power APP and Power  BI is refreshing information.

WE tried connecting to it using ODBC on python as well, But it is not working. We were able to connect to it a few weeks ago.

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: @LeonYue is “Could not establish a connection to server '<server name>'. This may indicate a problem with your network connection or firewall configuration. Check your network connection and try again.”

Comment: Please recheck your Azure SQL server [firewall settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule) if anything changed.

Comment: make sure you do not have the network connection error.

Comment: Hi @Pai, did the error solved now?

Comment: @LeonYue Will try this and let you know . Network connectivity is fine.

Answer (score 0):

According the error message, there are two things you can do.

1. Make sure your environment network connection is ok.
2. Recheck your [Azure SQL database firewall setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule), add the client IP to firewall roles.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leon! Thanks for the response, This did not work. We have also added the IP address. We are not able to login from the same system that we setup the Database.